# Measurability of a regular set

Tags: measure-theory

This is a problem from an old comp exam.

Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure on $X$, with $\mu^*(X) < \infty$.
Suppose $E \subset X$ is regular, i.e. there is a $\mu^*$-measurable set $A \supset E$ with $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(E)$.
Show that $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable iff $\mu^*(E) + \mu^*(E^c) = \mu^*(X)$.

The forward implication is obvious.
I'm having trouble showing that $\mu^*(E) + \mu^*(E^c) = \mu^*(X)$ implies that $\mu^*(B) = \mu^*(B \cap E) + \mu^*(B \cap E^c)$ for any $B \subset X$.
In particular, I can't think of how to use the assumption $\mu^*(X) < \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $\mu^*$-measurability of $A$ we have 
$\mu^* (E) + \mu^*(E^c) = \mu^*(X) = \mu^*(A) + \mu^*(A^c)$

By regularity and finiteness we obtain $\mu^*(E^c) = \mu^*(A^c) < \infty$

By $\mu^*$-measurability of $A$ we have $\mu^*(E^c) = \mu(E^c \cap A) + \mu^*(E^c \cap A^c) = \mu(E^c \cap A) + \mu^*(A^c)$. Cancelling $\mu(E^c)$ which we can do by finiteness gives us

- $\mu^*(E^c \cap A) = 0$ which we will need in our final step.

By subadditivity we have

- $\mu^*(B \cap E) \leq \mu^*(B \cap A) $

By the $\mu^*$-measurability of $A$ we have

- $\mu^*(B\cap E^c) = \mu^*(B \cap E^c \cap A) + \mu^*(B \cap E^c\cap A^c) = \mu^*(B \cap E^c \cap A) + \mu^*(B \cap A^c)$

Combine these and our first result and we get

- $\mu^*(B \cap E) + \mu^*(B \cap E^c) \leq \mu^*(B \cap A)  + \mu^*(B \cap A^c) + \mu^*(B \cap E^c \cap A) \\ =\mu^*(B) + \mu^*(B \cap E^c \cap A) \leq \mu^*(B) + \mu^*(E^c \cap A) = \mu^*(B)$

This is a little messy but hopefully you can clean it up if need be.