# Outer Measurability of Regular Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X$ be a set and $\mu$ be a finite outer measure on $X$ $(\mu(X) < \infty)$. A set $E\subset X$ is called **regular** if there exists a $\mu$- measurable set $A$ such that $\mu (E) = \mu (A)$ and $E\subset A$. Then E is $\mu$ - measurable if and only if $\mu(X) = \mu(E)$ + $\mu (E^{c})$, where $E^{c}$ is the complement of $E$.

So the direction $``\Rightarrow"$ is trivial because of the definition of outer measure. For the $``\Leftarrow"$ direction, let $B \subset X$, we need to show that $\mu(B) = \mu(B \cap E)$ + $\mu(B\cap E^{c})$. Since $A$ is $\mu$ - measurable, $\mu(B) = \mu(B \cap A)$ + $\mu(B\cap A^{c}) \geq \mu(B\cap E)$ + $\mu(B \cap A^{c})$.From the fact $\mu(X) = \mu(E)$ + $\mu (E^{c})$ and $\mu(E) = \mu(A)$, we can see that $\mu(A^{c})$ = $\mu(E^{c})$ . I think the key here is to show that $\mu (B\cap A^{c})$ = $\mu(B\cap E^{c})$, but I'm stuck there. How should I proceed from there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measurability of a regular set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633213/measurability-of-a-regular-set)